# How to exclude certain words in regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have this regex to match username in my system: `/[a-zA-Z]+([_-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*$/`. It starts with letters and allows `numbers, _ and -`. But I dont want the username includes some words like `admin`, `facebook`, `official` etc. How can I add these words to the regex? I want to use one regex to manage all the constraints.

Comment: Can you explain why this all has to be done in just one regex instead of doing it the easy way?

Comment: `indexOf('facebook') < 0 then OK`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility:

```
^((?!admin|facebook|official)[a-zA-Z])((?!admin|facebook|official|[-_]{2})[-_0-9a-zA-Z])*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ELFw9T/4)

**Edit**: updated to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(?=((?!(admin|facebook|official)).)+$)[a-z]+[_-]?[0-9a-z]+$/i
```

## Check it:

```css
input { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; outline: none; }
:valid { border: 1px solid green; }
:invalid { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<input pattern="^(?=((?!(admin|facebook|official)).)+$)[a-zA-Z]+[_-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+$" autofocus>
```